# Merging different data sets which are at same frequency but do not start at common multiples of time step into a single Time series

Tags: time-series

I have 5 different data sets of temperature data which were all recorded with the time interval (16 min intervals).  The each dataset is about a year long for 2015 then 2017, 19, 20 and 21. I am missing 2016 and 2018. I am trying to make a time series from the all the data, with NANs at the missing time steps.

I created a datatable in R from all the data sets. This would make a TS but would ignore the missing values.

I created a separate data table from a sequence of times from the beginning to the end of the full time range at 16 minute intervals and then merged (using a common date column) with the previous data table.

This worked to a point but ignored the last two data tables as I discovered they were not recorded at times which were a multiple of the original timestep.  I can create a TS using the above at 1 minute intervals which captures all the data but this introduces a hugh amount of NANs in the TS.

I am trying to carry out seasonality analysis on the full data which is why I am trying this approach but if there is a better method would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is only for _programming_ questions. You might have better luck on [stats.se] or [datascience.se] (but please read their help documents to make sure before posting_.